# Getting a 'manifest element not declared' error

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my app run in landscape mode only, but for some reason I'm getting this very weird error and I have no idea why.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    package="WineLab.WineLab" android:versionCode="1"  android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
 <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"></application>
  <activity android:name="WineLab"
 android:screenOrientation="landscape"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
 </activity>
</manifest>
```

[image: Screenshot]

The above 'manifest' is underlined in blue and that's it. The error just says that the "manifest" element is not declared.

Comment: problem in `application` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Check you have declared your `</activity>` tag outside the `<application`

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="WineLab.WineLab" android:versionCode="1"  android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
 <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name=".WineLab"
 android:screenOrientation="landscape"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

**NOTE** : also need to add `<intent-filter>` in your activity

Comment: It's still giving me the same "manifest element not declared" error.

Comment: @Jane r u sure this is your whole manifest  file can share image of error

Comment: Could an IDE0006 error be causing this to happen? Because I have that one showing too

Comment: I included a screenshot into my post.

Comment: @Jane try to add theme in your application tag

Comment: as soon as I add my android-layout-xml schema then this error comes along.

Comment: can you share `android-layout-xml` @Jane

Comment: @Jane for test case try this `<activity android:name=".WineLab"`

Comment: @Jane what is the name of your activity

Answer (score 0):

this will work you have not entered the **.** in activity.

```
<activity android:name=".WineLab
```

Comment: have you used **Clean Project**?

Comment: Can you share the error image by doing on mouse hover on a manifest?

Comment: All it says when I hover is 'the manifest element is not declared." That's it, no extra info nothing

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my program running without fixing the manifest error - I deleted all of that code from the AndroidManifest and forgot about it. Thank you for the help.